# Connecting to a Usb peripheral

Tags: android-things

It looks like the UsbManager is gone in the build. How do we communicate with usb peripherals now?

Things like usb->serial etc using https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Peripheral HAL doesn't recognize usbserial based UART peripherals.

But if your usbserial device (ex: Arduino) exposes individual UART `TX` `RX` pins, you can communicate with it using the [UART Peripheral API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html).

Caveat:

- Don't forget to cross `TX` and `RX` when connecting the peripheral to the UART board of your development board
  [image: uart-cross]
- On Raspberry Pi 3, the console needs to be disabled, see: [UART peripherals on Android Things for Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127018/uart-peripherals-on-android-things-for-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: This is a good explanation of using a uart but what I'm really trying to find out is if there will be full usb support. I would like to eventually build an expansion board with cell, gps, and possible other peripherals. Being limited by the number of uarts could be a setback.

Comment: Ideally the HAL would add new `UartDevice` to the [Peripheral API](https://android-dot-devsite.googleplex.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) as they get plugged in. Maybe you can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request)?

Answer (score 2):

It is stated on the *known issues* part of the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) that USB support is disabled on the developer preview 1.

However I did a quick test on the Pi3 and high level peripherals such a keyboard work and send the correct events to the app. It is just the low level access what is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

As [@devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired) commented in the [Google's IoT Developers Community](https://plus.google.com/112090467711235891544/posts/78pNQa52Li2): USB accessory support is not currently enabled is the RC1 preview.