# Integrating GSM/GPRS modem with Raspberry Pi 3 with Android things

Tags: android, gsm, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am trying to make a module with the help of Android Things. I need to send temperature and pressure readings to a server over the internet with the help of GSM/GPRS modem. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with AndroidThings SDK. I am able to get temperature and pressure readings with the help of BMP 280 sensor but must use external GSM modem to send data to the server. Is it possible to integrate GSM modem with Android Things (Raspberry pi 3)? Where can I get resources to learn and do this, as I am new to Android Things and IoT?

Comment: It depends what protocol the GSM Modem uses to communicate. What is the name of your GSM modem? for example `SIM800L` then check the devices datasheet for the protocol it uses

Comment: I have JYMG-100 GSM/GPRS modem (http://www.actechinfosys.com/AWSGPRS.aspx) with me right now. Can you suggest any module which can be able to do this with AndroidThings and Raspberry pi 3?

Comment: You might be able to use UART, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151610/connecting-to-a-usb-peripheral/41151897#41151897  Otherwise I googled for your datasheet to understand the TX&RX and found nothing: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22JYMG-100%22+modem&* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Thanks for all the answers above. I worked on integrating SIM900 module in Android things with Raspberry Pi 3 board. I made a sample library project on GitHub as well.  I thought It would be helpful for others. Link: https://github.com/MacSimmy/Sim900AndroidThings

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can integrating JYMG-100 GSM/GPRS modem with Raspberry Pi 3 with Android things. For this You need:

1) hardware UART<->RS232 converter (for example like [that](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?cPath=346_325&products_id=5757&osCsid=1kndj4vea6md7r3v84ejuisj46)) because RP3 has 0..+5V UART input/outputs, but JYMG-100 GSM/GPRS modem - not UART, but RS232 interface with -12..+12V input/outputs, more details see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/110478/132328))

2) implement AT-command control of JYMG-100 GSM/GPRS modem (yes, You need datasheet with JYMG-100 AT-command set, like [this](http://www.propox.com/download/docs/SIM900_AT.pdf) for SIM900 GSM/GPRS module, but for common tasks, like SMS processing You can use "standard" AT-commans like [that](http://electronicsforu.com/resources/cool-stuff-misc/wanted-know-gsm-commands). If You didn't find datasheet for JYMG-100 just open its body and look what GSM/GPRS it use) via RP3 UART like in [this](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback) tutorial (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41127018/6950238) question of [proppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656408/proppy) is very helpful). So, You just have to sent `String` with AT-command to JYMG-100 and get and analyze response `String`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. I have been able to integrate SIM800L TO RPI3 running Android Things via UART and AT commands. I am however using it for sending SMS and not for Internet connectivity. I do not see an issue in achieving that as well.

Ensure you use proper voltages for Sim800l module as the range is between 3.7v to 4.2v max and peak current consumption is around 2amps. Use a good quality power supply to prevent network dropouts.

Hope this answers your question.