# Raspberry Pi Ultimate GPS Hat - UART buffer is completely filled with 0 values

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

In the meanwhile, I bought two [Raspberry Pi Ultimate GPS Hat](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2324). I thought the first GPS Hat might be broken, but both of them shows the same behaviour - the buffer received from the UART, is completely filled with 0 values (512 bytes)!

See *processBuffer(byte[] buffer, int count)* Method in the *NmeaGpsModule* class.

```
private void processBuffer(byte[] buffer, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (mParser.getFrameStart() == buffer[i]) {
            handleFrameStart();
        } else if (mParser.getFrameEnd() == buffer[i]) {
            handleFrameEnd();
        } else if (buffer[i] != 0){
            //Insert all other characters except '0's into the buffer
            mMessageBuffer.put(buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the [GPS](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps) example with the following settings:

```
public static final int UART_BAUD = 9600;
public static final float ACCURACY = 2.5f; // From GPS datasheet
```

Any ideas? Whats wrong?

Comment: Strangely I had a similar issue (all the buffer filled with 0s) when using a NEO-6M with an arduino mega. The problem turned out to be the wrong baud rate... Maybe it's worth trying other baud rates (4800, 19200, 57600, 115200)

Comment: And... now I saw that you tagged it with raspberry-pi3, but the adafruit site you linked says "Does not work with the Pi 3 at this time"

Comment: You are right, but on the [UART GPS sample for Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/gps) Page the  Raspberry Pi Ultimate GPS Hat is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this post: [UART peripherals on Android Things for Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127018/uart-peripherals-on-android-things-for-raspberry-pi-3)

The console is flooding the serial with junk. Need to disable the output to clean that up.