# How to enable USB API in Android Things for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am working on a project which involves a Raspberry Pi 3 Module B Board with Android Things OS on it. My android application running on Raspberry Pi3 needs to communicate with an external hardware over USB.
But,it has been mentioned in the Known Issues - https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html that the USB API is currently disabled.

Is there any way for enabling the USB APIs in Android Things?
Any help or guidance for the same will be highly appreciated!﻿
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This API has been added to the Developer Preview 3, see the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_3)

Answer (score 3):

May be [this](http://android.geek.nz/i-need-more-uarts-android-things/) post helps. Needs to be some tricks on `ttyUSBx`.

Comment: Since `AT DP3` `USB/Serial connection` directly supported via peripheral manager as `UART` interface. Useful information can be found at [this](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/usb-communications) post. So no need to use `USB API`. However `USB API` also was enabled with `AT DP3`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Peripheral `HAL` doesn't recognize `USB` serial based `UART` peripherals. However, if your `USB` serial device (ie Raspberry PI) exposes individual `UART` `TX` & `RX` pins, you can communicate with it using the [UART Peripheral API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html).

**Note:**

- `TX` and `RX` must be crossed while connecting the peripheral to the `UART` board of your development board .

[image]

- On Raspberry Pi 3, the console needs to be disabled :  [UART peripherals on Android Things for Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127018/uart-peripherals-on-android-things-for-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: Thank you @OBX for your prompt reply. I just checked the I/O Pinout diagram of Raspberry Pi 3. It has just one UART. But my devices needs minimum 2 UARTS. Any way out for this?