# UART Communication doesn't work on defalult image Android Things

Tags: android, uart, android-things

I have a big problem and I have searched thoroughly and found nothing... I'm using Android things as a central device in a system with other devices connectected. We are using the UART pins of the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B to communicate with the other devices.

When I use the default image burned with the Android Things utility and install the app through LAN connection, the app starts but it doesn't respod to any UART commands (as if nothing was being received). Note that the same code works if we burn a custom image with that app. The Raspberry also shows an error saying "bluetooth has stopped" even though I am not using the bluetooth... No error is shown in the logcat console so I don't know what is it causing it... I have tried reburning the image several times, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41127018/6950238)?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the code you are using to access the UART from your app?